# How to customize "not enough columns given to draw the requested chart" message?

Tags: javascript, css, google-visualization

Is there any way to customize Google charts to prevent them from displaying this 'red' message? E.g., silently drawing nothing instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a bunch of events, methods and tools google charts / visualization offers for customizing error handling, error messages and so on.

For example, see https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#errordisplay or https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/examples#querywrapper

According to what you are asking for, the easiest way would be to simply attach an errorhandler and in that handler, remove the error through `google.visualization.errors`.

Like this :

```
function errorHandler(errorMessage) {
    //curisosity, check out the error in the console
    console.log(errorMessage);

    //simply remove the error, the user never see it
    google.visualization.errors.removeError(errorMessage.id);
}

function drawChart(json) {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(json); //here, JSON is buggy
    var options = {
      title: 'test'
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    //attach the error handler here, before draw()
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'error', errorHandler);    

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

viola! Try add the `errorHandler` and `google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'error', errorHandler);` to your existing code, and see the difference (this is all you need).

Answer (score 0):

you might miss to declare any variables .
E.g var data
i also got same error ,finally i found that i missed to declare 
 data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(sourcedata); and i changed that as

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(sourcedata);
```