# Remove google chart error message and display an empty chart when there's no data from the database

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

This is my script for google chart. I'm trying to display an empty chart if there's no data and hides the message “not enough columns given to draw the requested chart”. Do you know what's wrong with my code? That error message still appears whenever there's no data. I've refer to [How to customize "not enough columns given to draw the requested chart" message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559675/how-to-customize-not-enough-columns-given-to-draw-the-requested-chart-message) but it does not work for my case. Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
        google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

        // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartCampaign);

        function errorHandler(errorMessage) {
            //curisosity, check out the error in the console
            console.log(errorMessage);

            //simply remove the error, the user never see it
            google.visualization.errors.removeError(errorMessage.id);
        }

        function drawChartCampaign() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?= generateChartOverview($row['campaignId'], $start_date, $end_date, false, true, $ad); ?>);

            var options = {
                title: '',
                pointSize: 3,
                animation: { duration: 1000, easing: 'out' },
                hAxis: {title: 'Date', titleTextStyle: {color: '#999999'}<?php if($boolInterval){ echo " , showTextEvery : $showTextEvery"; } ?>},
                vAxis: {title: 'Clicks / Views', titleTextStyle: {color: '#999999'}, viewWindowMode:'explicit', viewWindow:{ min:0 }}  
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div_adsdetails'));

            //attach the error handler here, before draw()
            google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'error', errorHandler);

            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Do you know what you get from `<?= generateChartOverview($row['campaignId'], $start_date, $end_date, false, true, $ad); ?>` in that case?

Comment: Yes, if there's data, it will show the chart and it's working normally. But when there's no data yet, the chart shows that error message.

Comment: I understand that but what is the result of `<?= generateChartOverview($row['campaignId'], $start_date, $end_date, false, true, $ad); ?>`? An empty string, an empty array, an array of empty arrays or some garbage? What is coming in `arrayToDataTable()` as argument?

Answer (score 0):

I manage this error catching them with google event listener

```
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.querySelector('#chartContainer'));
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'error', function (googleError) {
        google.visualization.errors.removeError(googleError.id);
        //here you can write your custom message or nothing if you want remove
        alert("error catch")
    });
  chart.draw(yourData, yourOptions);
```